# Send SMS via a USB Dongle/Python

Tags: python, sms

I want to send sms using a dongle. I found the following code from [this](http://linux-101.org/script/python-code-sending-sms-messages-usb-connected-mobile-phone) site and adopted it. But it gives the flowing error.  Can somebody please help me to make this script working.

Error:

```
   raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Code:

```
import serial
import time

class TextMessage:
    def __init__(self, recipient="0123456789", message="TextMessage.content not set."):
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.content = message

    def setRecipient(self, number):
        self.recipient = number

    def setContent(self, message):
        self.content = message

    def connectPhone(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 460800, timeout=5)
        time.sleep(1)

    def sendMessage(self):
        self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(chr(26))
        time.sleep(1)

    def disconnectPhone(self):
        self.ser.close()

sms = TextMessage("0123456789","This is the message to send.")
sms.connectPhone()
sms.sendMessage()
sms.disconnectPhone()
```

Comment: Let us know your OS and your dongle device type

Comment: @MostafaR: OS : Ubuntu...Dongle : Huawei Mobile Broadband, Model E1550, HSDPA USBDongle

Comment: and has the dongle enumerated as /dev/ttyACM0 ?

Comment: Also, it's absolutely horrible to just fire AT commands off at the dongle without checking the response you get back.

Answer (score 1):

Most of USB GSM modems are using a RS-232 to USB chip inside to emulate RS-232 interface on your USB port.

According to my knowledge drivers of these chips are using `/dev/ttyACM` or `/dev/ttyUSB` as their interface.

So if you're sure your device is recognizable by linux kernel, you can check for `/dev/ttyUSB` in your file system and if this exists (Of course when the device is connected), then replace `/dev/ttyACM` in your source code with `/dev/ttyUSB`.

Also to list all of your serial ports available and devices they are connected to, you can use this command:

```
ls -l /sys/class/tty/tty*
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, when I plugged the dongle /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0,/sys/class/tty/ttyUSB1,/sys/class/tty/ttyUSB2 were there?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage I think you should test them one-by-one.

Comment: It worked fine after changing self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 460800, timeout=5)..Thanks for your help..:)

Answer (score 1):

You must have copied all the code
can be seen from the line

```
self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 460800, timeout=5)
```

and error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Just check which device file is used by your usb dongle. 
An easy way is to remove the dongle, list all the files under /dev directory, then plugin the dongle and check for any new file added.

Just put that file in the code.

Hopefully it will work, and you will get new error :)

Answer (score 0):

for windows users

```
     self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 460800, timeout=5)
```

you can be replaced this '/dev/ttyACM0' with 'COM25'. the port 'COM25' is my own port
To check the port of your modem, you go to control panel --->on the right top of the screen change the 'view by' to large icon. then click on phones and modem ------>when it comes up select the tab named modem and u will see the list of installed modem in your computer. Identify your current modem and access its port

```
    self.ser = serial.Serial('yourport', 460800, timeout=5)
```

it will solve this error for windows users

```
    serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are not encoded, that will be an error when you try to run your code